# How to aggregate count of unique values in a column of pgsql table & display them in columns?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

In Postgresql, one of my columns contain only contain one of 5 values. One of those 5 values is "Matured". I am trying to write a query that counts how many times "Matured" appears in that column for a specific cut of the whole table.

The following query produces the error: `syntax error at or near "Matured"`.

The query:

```
select count(case when stagename is Matured end) from db_table
```

ALTERNATIVELY, I have the following result:

```
"Matured";694
"Credit Approved";3
"Delinquent";572
"Current";1356
"Canceled";16
```

using the query:

```
select distinct stagename,
       sum(case when stagename is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       from db_table
       group by stagename
```

But I need that result in columns not rows. Like so:

```
           |Matured   |Credit Approved   |Delinquent    |Current    |Canceled
```

stage_count       |694       |3                  |572           |1356         |16

Any ideas?

Comment: `I am trying to write a query that counts how many times "Matured" appears in that column` - Why not just: `select count(*) from table where column = 'Matured'` ?

Comment: Why do you need it in columns, not rows? The first thing that comes to mind for me is `select stagename, count(*) from db_table group by stagename` and then using something like python to do a `Transpose()`. There are probably ways of doing it in PSQL, but I dont understand that column requirement.

Comment: Actually, I didn't think of using R to do the transpose, was trying to get everything in one query. Thanks! PS: I need it in one table because I am doing a month wise split of a large table. It needs to be in the same table as the rest of the month wise summary else it would lose context.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed single quotes for Matured in your query as well as case when statement is not correct that is why it is returning syntax error. You can use below query to get required result. 
You can also read about [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) function of postgres.

```
select count(case when stagename = 'Matured' then 1 end),
count(case when stagename = 'Credit Approved' then 1 end),  
count(case when stagename = 'Delinquent'  then 1 end),
count(case when stagename = 'Current' then 1 end),
count(case when stagename = 'Canceled' then 1 end)
from db_table
```

**Note:** If your column contains leading and trailing space then use trim function with your column name and then compare.